# Splitting inout array into multiple inout signals in verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I need to do something like this. I need to split the array into individual signals. I don't have an enable signal to specify direction. And, "assign" statement is not way to go. Any other suggestions?

```
module conv (
  inout [1:0] array,
  inout       a,
  inout       b 
);

 assign {a, b} = array;

endmodule
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to *alias* a signal's name. See section 10.11 Net aliasing in the IEEE 1800-2017 LRM.

```
module conv ( inout [1:0] array, inout a, inout b );

  alias {a,b} = array;

endmodule
```

Comment: But, I thought alias is not a synthesizable construct

Comment: It might not be supported by your tool yet, but there is no reason a synthesis tool would have a problem supporting it.

Answer (score 0):

A Verilog way of doing the same thing would be:

```
module conv ( .array(io), .a(io[1]), .b(io[0]) );
  inout [1:0] io;
endmodule
```

This is IEEE 1364-2001 and later complaint. (Might be IEEE 1364-1995 complaint too, but the LRM isn't as clear). If you need something that absolutely needs to be Verilog-95 complient, then you can use the bellow. I don't think the below support connect by name at module instantiation.

```
module conv ( io, io[1], io[0] );
  inout [1:0] io;
endmodule
```

There is also the primitive `tran`. I haven't use synthesizer that supports it even though it is in IEEE 1364-1995.

```
module conv ( inout [1:0] array, inout a, b );
  tran t1(array[1],a);
  tran t0(array[0],b);
endmodule
```

If your tools support SystemVerilog `alias`, then that would be the preferred way to go. I have rarely seen the styles above used even though LRM support been there for decades.

If your synthesizer doesn't like `alias` or any of the above, then check the standard cell library. It might have an equivalent special cell.